# Is there a simpler way of unpacking a tuple?

Tags: python

The below is an example of some code I wrote in a RPG game that I've been working on. Upon winning a battle, the stats are updated in the level_up() function, and returned in the form of a list.
Which brings up my question. Is there a better way of writing the below code?

```
stats = level_up()
level = stats[0]
exp = stats[1]
exp_nextlev = stats[2]
health = stats[3]
defense = stats[4]
attack = stats[5]
speed = stats[6]
```

Comment: `level, ..., speed = level_up()`

Comment: comma separated variables = stats

Answer (score 5):

```
level, exp, exp_nextlev, health, defense, attack, speed = stats
```

Comment: That isn't working. It says that the stats went missing.

Comment: @SpencerDuffin  Python has no error message "stats went missing". This answer is completely correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the stats (health, attack, etc.) were set to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I would write that as a named tuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Stats = namedtuple('Stats', ['level', 'exp', 'exp_nextlev', 'health', 'defense', 'attack', 'speed'])

def level_up():
    # blah code blah
    return Stats(level, exp, exp_nextlev, health, defense, attack, speed)

stats = level_up()
```

Then you can rust refer to

```
stats.exp
stats.health
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

It's not shorter, but better style in my opinion, to just return a dictionary like this `{"level": ..., "exp":..., ...}` from the function. When you later acces values of the dictionary your code will be as readable as with different variables for every item.